# Android TextView set Marquee,How to remove the shadow at left and right of the TextView

Tags: android, marquee

I set the Marquee of TextView,and its running well,but when the text moving, there are shadows at left and right of the TextView,how to remove the shadows?
my xml code

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/tv_result"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:ellipsize="marquee"
  android:focusable="true"
  android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
  android:gravity="center_vertical"
  android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
  android:singleLine="true"
  android:textColor="@color/white"
  android:textSize="20sp" />
```

There are not shadows of the text,just like Masks align the left and right of the TextView.When marquee is running,they are displayed.And dismiss when marquee is stop.

Answer (score 5):

extends the TextView overwrite onDraw()

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call `setFadingEdgeLength(0)`, no need to extend TextView.

Answer (score -1):

use setShadowLayer on your textview

```
tv_result.setShadowLayer(0,0,0,0)
```

Comment: There are not shadows of the text,just like Masks align the left and right of the TextView.When marquee is running,they are displayed.And dismiss when marquee is stop.